# How to configure OData and Radzen Blazor (client and server) for Net Core 6 and Odata 8

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, odata

Radzen documentation and examples for versions lower than Net Core 6 and Odata 8.

The first problem is in the response I get from server, does not match in return type.

The second filters

Here is the service configuration:

```
public async Task<ODataServiceResult<PersonDto>> GetPeopleAsync(string filter = default(string), int? top = default(int?), int? skip = default(int?), string orderby = default(string), string expand = default(string), string select = default(string), bool? count = default(bool?))
{
    var uri = new Uri(http.BaseAddress, $"api/Persons");
    uri = uri.GetODataUri(filter: filter, top: top, skip: skip, orderby: orderby, expand: expand, select: select, count: count);
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    var response = await http.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    return await response.ReadAsync<ODataServiceResult<PersonDto>>();
}
```

Here is the controller configuration:

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 10, MaxNodeCount = 1000)]
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<PersonDto> Get()
    {
        var people = context.Persons.ConvertToDto().AsQueryable();
        return people;
    }
```

Good if write query

```
https://localhost:7069/api/Persons?$top=5&$skip=0&$count=true
```

in browser it works I get results(5) as expected.

But for filters with query

```
https://localhost:7069/api/Persons?$filter=(LastName+%3d%3d+null+%3f+%27%27+%3a+LastName).ToLower().Contains(%27s%27.ToLower())&$top=5&$skip=0&$count=true
```

I got this error :

> {"Message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. ')' or operator expected at position 10 in '(LastName == null ? '' : LastName).ToLower().Contains('d'.ToLower ())'.","ExceptionMessage":"')'

Comment: Have you configured for the EDM approach? Your return result looks as if you trying to receive an Odata response.

Comment: no, i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your API server:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<IQueryable<Person>> Get()
    {
        IQueryable<Person> items = entityService.AsQueryable();

        return Ok(items);
    }
```

```
    builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options =>
    {
        options.AddRouteComponents(routePrefix: "odata", GetEdmModel())
            .Select()
            .Count()
            .Filter()
            .Expand()
            .OrderBy()
            .SetMaxTop(maxTopValue: 100);
    });
```

```
    public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.EntitySet<Person>(name: "Persons")
            .EntityType.HasKey(person=> person.Id);
...
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

```
public readonly struct ItemsPageResult<TItem>
{
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Items { get; }

    public int TotalItemsCount { get; }

    public ItemsPageResult(IEnumerable<TItem> items, int totalItemsCount)
    {
        Items = items;
        TotalItemsCount = totalItemsCount;
    }
}
```

Your question shows your using a DTO which is fine. Be aware that your breaking a benefit of passing the query all the way back to the SQL engine if your using a provider that returns an IQueryable like EntityFramework does. If you want to map to a DTO, I suggest do it with an `Expression`, the nuget package AutoMapper can do this for you.

In your client:

```
    public async ValueTask<ItemsPageResult<ItemContextResult<TItem>>> GetItemsAsync(
        int startIndex,
        int count,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) => await GetItemsAsync(startIndex, count, queryString: "", cancellationToken);

    public async ValueTask<ItemsPageResult<ItemContextResult<TItem>>> GetItemsAsync(
        int startIndex,
        int count,
        string queryString,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var query = $"odata/{EndPoint}?{queryString}&$skip={startIndex}&$top={count}&$count=true";

        OdataResponce<TItem> response = await HttpClient.GetContentAsync<OdataResponce<TItem>>(relativeUrl: query, cancellationToken);

        var contextItems = response.Items.Select((item, index) => new ItemContextResult<TItem>(item, index + startIndex)).ToList();

        return new ItemsPageResult<ItemContextResult<TItem>>(contextItems, totalItemsCount: response.TotalItemsCount);
    }
```

`GetContentAsync` comes from `RESTFulSense` change it to `GetFromJsonAsync` for a plain `HttpClient`.

```
public readonly struct ItemContextResult<TItem>
{
    public TItem Item { get; }
    public int Offset { get; }

    public ItemContextResult(TItem item, int offset)
    {
        Item = item;
        Offset = offset;
    }
}
```

```
public class OdataResponce<TItem>
{
    [JsonPropertyName(name: "@odata.context")]
    public string ContextUrl { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonPropertyName(name: "@odata.count")]
    public int TotalItemsCount { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName(name: "value")]
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Items { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

The `ItemContextResult` is not required its a little extra I add to get the relative line number into the result.

In my case this passes the Query to EntityFramework...

The comes from a solution where im using:

```
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="11.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="RESTFulSense" Version="2.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.3.1" />
    ....
```

Client:

```
    <PackageReference Include="RESTFulSense.WebAssembly" Version="1.0.0" />
```

Comment: When your configure for the EDM approach you will have another endpoint route `odata/Persons`

Comment: It works thank you very much, just that I used Dto builder.EntitySet<PersonDto>(name: "Persons"),